Where do I need to go to find a Snorlax in Pokémon FireRed?
Where should I go to find a Snorlax in Pokémon FireRed?

Just like Pokémon Red, Blue, Green and Yellow before them, there are exactly two Snorlax in Pokémon FireRed:

One on Route 12 (south of Lavender Town)

One on Route 16 (west of Celadon City)


Both are asleep, blocking their respective roads, and only start an encounter (i.e. attack the player) after being awoken by the Poké Flute. If neither one currently exists in your game, then you've likely already battled and defeated them, and you can no longer catch a Snorlax in your game. You will have to resort to other methods (e.g. trading) to obtain one.

iirc, (unless this only exists in newer games) the two Snorlax (like all other stationary encounters) respawn after you defeat the elite four again. also the two Snorlax serve as roadblocks to prevent you from getting to fuscia until you've dealt with Lavender town

@EmCeeChupitheUndying: I think respawning of non-legendary overworld Pokémon that were knocked out rather than caught was only added in HGSS (or possibly DPPt at the earliest).

Note that the Pokemon daycare on Four Island allows two Pokemon to be placed at once, and therefore allows Pokemon to be bred. So if you can borrow a Snorlax from a friend long enough to generate an Egg, you can still get one with your Trainer ID.

@EmCeeChupitheUndying I can confirm that overworld Pokemon do not respawn after the Elite 4 in third generation Pokemon games (Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald, Fire Red/Leaf Green)
